# cytoscape.js and canvasXpress mixup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cytoscape.js

I am new to cytoscape.js and I have encountered a strange behavior when I have a div with my network (cy) and a canvasXpress element in the same div. The body structure is like so:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
   <div class="col-sm-6 result box" id="divHeatmap">
     <!-- This div is replaced by a canvasXpress element-->
     <div><canvas id="canvas1"></canvas></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 result row" style="padding-left:30px;" id="divNetwork">
     <div class="col-sm-12 row result box" style="padding-left:30px; ">
         <div class="result row">
             <div id="cy"></div>
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

cy is created correctly (it works in every other case tested) as is the canvasXpress element. The trouble starts when my pointer hovers over the canvasXpress element and then returns over the cy network. When this happens the layers of the network seem to be broken. I can click the nodes but they either disappear or get stuck on the pointer (unless I right click). Moreover, the edges point to random points when i click at anything. My suspicion is that the canvasXpress element messes with the z-index of the cy layers. Do you have any idea what might be happening? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Don't share the same div for multiple lib containers.  That's not a good idea in general.

Do this

- some div

  - viz A div
  - viz B div

And just stack the A and B div on top of each other with CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Maybe I misunderstood, but am I not doing this already? 

- div
  - divHeatmap
  - div divNetwork

Comment: I must have glossed over your example.  Maybe it's the column classes you're using?  It's hard to say.  It would be helpful to see a jsbin or a jsfiddle

Comment: I tried a number of things and that's what I learned. I placed the heatmap in a completely unrelated div and still the mix-up occurs. No event listeners from canvasXpress are to blame (I disabled them all and still got the same error). The exact moment the problem occurs is when I actually click on the cytoscape graph after I have hovered over the canvasXpress heatmap (for example, actions like zoom still work before I click on my graph). Other  nonXpress canvases do not trigger the problem.

Comment: Some specifics on what's the mixup:
1. A click on whitespace (without holding it) "grabs" the graph and can move it around (normally it does nothing), also the round shadow, that indicates you are holding the click, appears. You have to right click to leave the graph alone.
2. A click on a node either makes the node disappear or ,again, "grabs" the whole graph.
3. Once I click anywhere in the graph, zoom doesn't work any more.
4. After a couple clicks, nodes and edges appear and disappear randomly (in their initial positions or in positions were I "moved" them with previous clicks)

Comment: There's no way to tell what your issue is without seeing a live demo.  If everything works without CanvasXpress, then I strongly suspect CanvasXpress is the problem.  Cytoscape runs isolated and shouldn't conflict with anything.  If CanvasXpress does anything odd globally, you'll have to ask them to fix their code.

Comment: If I wanted to create a workaround, how could I "re-draw" my cy object from scratch? I believe I could use the mouseover listener to initiate the re-drawing but how could I destroy the old (affected) one and remake the same graph? I tried using cy.forceRender() with no success. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: Not possible.  There's too much low level caching and optimisations to allow for that.  If CanvasXpress is doing something to pollute the global scope etc, try putting it in an iframe so it's isolated.